# Open file on Mac from iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone

I want to open a file on my Mac by selecting it from my iPhone. I do not want to open the file on my iPhone. Is there an app or method to do this?

What I'm looking for is similar to how Apple's old iTunes Remote app works (from my iPhone I browse the media files located on my Mac, in iTunes, then my Mac plays the media file) but with any file on my computer.

Comment: These easiest way would be to AirDrop the file to the Mac, and then open from there.

Comment: Can you expand on the use case?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Let me expand on this a little. All the files are already on my Mac. I want to use my iPhone like a remote of sorts to tell the Mac which file it should open. Specifically, I want to open .mkv and .mp3 files, as well as other kinds of media.

Comment: How is this question worth downvotes? Constructive criticism on how I can improve it would be more welcome.

Comment: Logitech did a remote app once among others

Comment: Even with iTunes remote, the iPhone does not see the Mac files : it is a network data transfert between the 2 devices with a specific protocol.

Comment: You’ve only reiterated what you already said about music files.  There already exits apps that allow this.  What is the use case of using a tiny screen with a tightly controlled and limited UI to open files on a computer that is already infinitely more capable for this task?